# How to write arbitrary map to parque with spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I will be parsing a bunch of json objects with spark and writing them out to parquet for searching and analysis later. Most of the json has a regular schema that maps directly to parquet, but there is one section where I have a data object that can have arbitrary fields and values with arbitrary data types.

Are there any thoughts on how to handle this? I can not put a Map[String, Any] in a dataframe.

Comment: I guess you'll have to serialize / deserialize your `Map[String, Any]` before saving / after reading, so that as far a Parquet is concerned this is just a single String column.

Comment: I was really hoping for something better than that. So the number of fields isn't really arbitrary there are maybe only like 20 different ones that will show up. Maybe I will just make a bunch of nullable columns for every field that might show up.